# Display Problem - VirtualBox Ubuntu 20.04.01 LTS

Tags: virtualbox, display, dell

I installed Ubuntu 20.04.01 LTS in VirtualBox today and the full-screen display just doesn't appear clear. The VirtualBox Extensions are installed.

My web search revealed nothing that I want to accept as fact. My experience using Ubuntu / Linux is just enough to be dangerous so I'm here seeking help.

Any assistance you provide will be much appreciated.

System Description:

Laptop: Dell Inspiron 15-7579
RAM: 12GB
Display Adapter: Intel HD 620
Video Memory: 1GB

Thanks,
j

Answer (score 0):

Okay. I clicked on View in the small menu at the bottom of the desktop and expanded Virtual Machine 1 or Virtual Desktop 1, then changed the selection from 125% to 100%. The resolution instantly improved.

That appears to have solved the problem. Lesson Learned: Spend more time researching current settings.

j